# Not understanding the Join Function

Tags: php, sql

Thanks in advance for any time you spend on my question.

I am trying to display data in a way that will display the manufacturer as a name instead of a number.

Basically when they store the data they choose a manufacturer from a drop down which is generated from a table.. IE Trogues = 1  so products stores the #1 so I know that any beer is associated with trogues is 1. Now I want to display the data but instead of having a 1 I would like to have Trogues be displayed. Where you see manufacturer in the echo code below..

I am not understanding the process logic here..

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM products 
LEFT JOIN manufacturer 
ON product.manufacturer = manufacturer.id  
ORDER BY manufacturer.id, product.id";


$query = mysql_query($sql);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
echo "

<div class=reportclientproduct>".$row['manufacturer']."  -  <a href=".$row['website']." target=_blank>".$row['product']."</a></div>";
}
```

Comment: you'll need to look into joins - pretty basic stuff, so there will be many examples

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the query like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT man.id AS manufac, products.product AS prod FROM products 
    LEFT JOIN manufacturer as man
    ON product.manufacturer = manufacturer.id  
    ORDER BY manufacturer.id, product.id";

$query = mysql_query($sql);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) { 
    echo "
    ".$row['manufac']." - ".$row['prod']."

    ";
}
```

Assuming that the table products had a column named `manufacturer` which holds the ID of the manufacturer, and that both tables have columns name `ID` which hold the ID of the table item.

Also the JOIN functions may vary based on the database you use. But the aforementioned method is for mysql.

Comment: Also add a group by the manufacturer.ID in case multiple records are in the lookup table

Comment: it doesn't like this statement now. while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

Comment: @ScottKowalski if you edit your question and add the structure of your table, I can edit my answer to fit your needs :)

Comment: Edited the original post with your code above and my display code.. PHP makes me feel very stupid some days.. So the Table Products has a field manufacturer. The table Manufacturer has an field ID which is the primary key.

Comment: @ScottKowalski I meant the table structure. For example product: ( ID | Name | Manufacturer | Price | Some other Data | ... | Last Column ) manufacturer: ( ID | Name | Area | Some other Data | ... | Last Column )

Comment: The table Manufacturer has an field ID which is the primary key. Wouldn't I need to create a "display" name for the combined info? 2 = Bells so display bells in that line?

Comment: @ScottKowalski, probably this is your problem :)

Comment: table Manufacturer |id|name |

Comment: OK So the INFO is Displaying.. BUT it's Displaying a the Number is stored in products and not the Name of the Manufacturer stored in the manufacturer table

Comment: @ScottKowalski I edited my answer, check the new code.

Comment: it's giving me an error Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in beers/index.php on line 61 ------------- while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

Comment: @ScottKowalski It means that the query fails somewhere, can't you try to execute it via terminal/phpmyadmin ? Also have you checked stuff like lower/upper case chars and etc? check the edited code :)

Comment: running it on phpmadmin #1054 - Unknown column 'man.name' in 'field list'

Comment: @ScottKowalski yeah, try the edited code. :) Also i apologize for the long conversation, but you don't have enough rep to open a chat room.

Comment: Not a problem.. I appreciate the help.. here's the next error from phpadmin -------- #1054 - Unknown column 'products.name' in 'field list' ----- the field is manufacturer in products table and in the manufacturer table it's name

Comment: 'products.name' should become 'products.product' will edit the answer shortly

Comment: Still getting an error on the while statement..mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in index.php on line 61 === while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {